# C# Thread not closing (appears to crash) when using delegate to announce data

Tags: c#, multithreading, visual-studio-2015, .net-4.5

So I have run into an odd situation. I have been using a pattern successfully for a while now to communicate data between 2 threads. Assume there are 2 threads:

Thread A (GUI thread)
Thread B (polling a piece of equipment in the background for data)

Thread B is executing the PollStatus function then sleeping the thread for a wait period. When it gets the data, it raises a delegate event in Thread A, which marshals back to Thread A to update some labels with the data.

Thread A Code:

```
    private delegate void LabJackUSB_OnDataAvailableCallback(LabJackRef.Status LabJackStatus);
    private void LabJackUSB_OnDataAvailable(LabJackRef.Status LabJackStatus)
    {
        if (this.InvokeRequired)
        {
            this.Invoke(new LabJackUSB_OnDataAvailableCallback(LabJackUSB_OnDataAvailable), new object[] { LabJackStatus });
        }
        else
        {
            // Do something with data here
        }
    }
```

Thread B Code:

```
    public delegate void DataAvailable(LabJackRef.Status LabJackStatus);
    public event DataAvailable OnDataAvailable;

    private bool PollStatus(StepDefinition CurrentStep)
    {
        GetData();            
        AnnounceDataAvailable();
        return false;
    }

    private void AnnounceDataAvailable()
    {
        if (OnDataAvailable != null)
        {
            OnDataAvailable(USBStatus);
        }
    }
```

The thread is a while loop that executes the step, then sleeps the thread. The while loop continues until the state machine has performed its closing steps and sets the WorkerState.StateMachineComplete flag to true, at which point the while loop exits and the thread should close.

```
    protected void Worker(object Worker)
    {
        while (true)
        {
            // see if we are waiting to close the thread
            if (((ThreadInfo)Worker).CloseThread)
            {
                // set flag to exit worker when complete
                WorkerState.ThreadClosing = true;

                // if we have finished closing the state machine, 
                // we can exit the while loop to close the thread
                if (WorkerState.StateMachineComplete)
                    break;

                // otherwise, jump to the last step
                StateMachine.JumpToLast(WorkerStateMachine);
            }

            // run the state machine
            StateMachine.ExecuteStep(WorkerStateMachine, WorkerState);

            // wait for the time defined in the current step
            ((ThreadInfo)Worker).WaitHandle.WaitOne(WorkerState.DelayTimeMS);
        }
    }
```

Now this has been working well in multiple cases (no issues). For some reason when I am us the announce function it will not close, but no break points inside the while loop will stop the debugger. To me that means the while loop is no longer looping, but I don't know how that could be. I am not getting any unhandled exceptions in my application, so no clues there.

If I just comment out the announce function, the thread closes no problem, so I know the problem is not in the code to get the data or set the labels.

If I comment out the Thread A portion that does anything with the data, the error is still there, but if I don't subscribe to the event in Thread A, it will close properly.

Honestly I am at a loss on even how to start debugging this since the debugger is not being able to stop anywhere in the loop that is waiting to close.

Any ideas would be appreciated!

Thanks,
John Vickers

Comment: Two basic reasons why a thread does not appear to execute any code.  It exited or it deadlocked.  Deadlock is the very likely scenario here, Invoke() is a dangerous method.  It can only complete when the UI thread isn't busy executing code.  Like trying to get the thread to exit.  Use Debug > Windows > Threads and have a look-see at what the main thread is doing.

Comment: That window is empty for me, even when I know I have multiple threads running. Is there something I have to enable to be able to see them?

Comment: Debug > Break All.

Comment: Ah, I was able to verify this was the problem in another way. I set a global static variable when I enter my main UI closing event, then did not call the delegate if the flag was set. That allowed the thread to close properly. Is there something that can be tested to see if a form is closing without using a custom global flag?

Comment: Or is there a better way to update form elements on another thread without using a delegate?